# MSSQL conditional join condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join

I'm running into a bit of trouble with a join and was hoping the community might be able to help. I'm trying to join two tables TRANSACTIONS and TRANSTYPES on the transtypeID column. Easy enough. But transactions can be either foreign or domestic as denoted by the foreign_account column. Transaction types can be either foreign or domestic and could have multiple rows in the TRANSTYPES table.

I'm looking for a join that tries to match TRANSACTIONS and TRANSTYPES on ID, and foreign_account=foreign_account (x=x or null=null) when possible. If there is no match on foreign_account, then it takes the row with matching transtypeID and doesn't pay attention to the foreign_account column.

Table setup:

```
CREATE TABLE ##TRANSTYPES
        (transtypeID int,
        tt_name VARCHAR(50),
        foreign_account VARCHAR(5),
        additional_info VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO ##TRANSTYPES
    VALUES
    (1000,NULL,102.00),
    (1002, NULL, 103.00),
    (1002, 'x', 104.00),
    (1003, 'x', 105.00),
    (1003, 'x', 106.00), 
    (1003, NULL, 107.00),
    (1003, NULL, 108.00)
CREATE TABLE ##TRANSACTIONS
        (transtypeID int,
        foreign_account VARCHAR(5),
        balance DECIMAL(18,4))

INSERT INTO ##TRANSACTIONS
    VALUES  
        (1000,NULL,102.00 ),
        (1002, NULL, 103.00),
        (1002, 'x', 104.00),
        (1003, 'x', 105.00)
```

I started out with a simple join but I'm not getting the transaction of type 1003.

```
SELECT *
FROM ##transtypes TT
FULL outer JOIN ##transactions TRN
    ON tt.transtypeid = trn.transtypeID 
WHERE
    (TRN.foreign_account = TT.foreign_account
    OR (TRN.foreign_account IS NULL AND tt.foreign_account IS NULL))
```

I have a feeling that a cross-apply is in order, but I've never written one before. I'm banging my head against the wall on how to get a sub-query right. I'm trying to select top 1 on the TRANSTYPE table ordered by the foreign_account column, but no luck so far.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the join on the transtype ID. Then rank your rows and only keep the better match (i.e. same foreign_account when available):

```
SELECT tt_name, additional_info, transtypeID, foreign_account, balance
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    tt.tt_name,
    tt.additional_info, 
    trn.transtypeID,
    trn.foreign_account,
    trn.balance,
    row_number() 
      over (partition by tt.transtypeID, tt.tt_name 
            order by case when (trn.foreign_account = tt.foreign_account)
                            or (trn.foreign_account is null and tt.foreign_account is null)
                               then 1
                               else 2
                     end) as rn
  FROM ##transtypes tt 
  JOIN ##transactions trn ON trn.transtypeID = tt.transtypeID
) ranked
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thorsten - Thank you for your help. This gets me closer but doesn't give me the second transaction of type 1002.

Comment: Oh, sorry, you are right. I must not look for the best match per `transtypeID`, but for the best match per `transtypeID`+ `tt_name`. I've corrected my query.

Comment: Thorsten - this is great. I really appreciate your time.

Comment: I think this starts to break down when you have multiple transactions on the same transtypeID, same foreign_account flag. You'll only get the top one. if you add to the ##transactions table, (1003, 'x', 106.00), (1003, NULL, 107.00), you'll lose the $105,$106 transactions.

Comment: You made it look like there is always at most one record with `foreign_account` null and one with 'x' per `transtypeID`. If there can be more, then you are not looking for a single best record. Replace `ROW_NUMBER` by `RANK` to account for more matches. I hope that's it. `foreign_account` can only be either null or 'x', correct?

Comment: Apologies for the partial example. Yes- there can be multiple transactions for the same transaction type. I'll give the rank instead of row number a shot. Again, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could use a UNION ALL

```
SELECT  tt.tt_name,
    tt.additional_info, 
    trn.transtypeID,
    trn.foreign_account,
    trn.balance
FROM ##TRANSTYPES tt INNER JOIN ##TRANSACTIONS trn ON tt.foreign_account = trn.foreign_account

UNION ALL

SELECT  tt.tt_name,
    tt.additional_info, 
    trn.transtypeID,
    trn.foreign_account,
    trn.balance
FROM ##TRANSTYPES tt INNER JOIN ##TRANSACTIONS trn ON tt.transTypeID = trn.transTypeID
WHERE tt.foreign_account <> trn.foreign_account
OR (TRN.foreign_account IS NULL AND tt.foreign_account IS NULL)
```

Comment: David - this seems like a good solution. It's holding true as add transactions and duplicates. Thank you very much